# How to change ssh/sftp password if SSH shell is disabled and passwd command is disabled too

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

[WinSCP documentation says](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_change_password):

> If your SSH server allows changing your account password, go to *Session > Change Password* to request that.

And indeed, WinSCP can change SSH/SFTP password on server we use (but we not admin it).

I have tried:

- `ssh user@server` fails -> *"shell request failed on channel 0"* and
- `ssh user@server passwd` fails too -> *"exec request failed on channel 0"*

What are other possibilities to change password (from cmdline)?

WinSCP is running on Windows. I like to have commands for commandline which run on Linux. But if there is some Python solution, it could be good too.

At least I like to know *reasonable guess* of how WinSCP is changing the password, if the above options do not work.

- `sftp> version` returns  *"SFTP protocol version 3"*
- `sftp > help` doesn't seem to return any command useful for password change

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have shell access nor any other interface to change the password, you will have to use the `SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST` message to change the password (that's what WinSCP does)

Common Linux SSH toolset, the OpenSSH, cannot request password change this way. I do not know of any other Linux commandline tool that does.

---

Implementing this in Python is definitely possible. Common Python SSH library, Paramiko, does not support this either though, imo.

But if you modify its code slightly, it can do it. Locate [the following code in `_parse_service_accept` in `auth_handler.py`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/2.12.0/paramiko/auth_handler.py#L379-L382):

```python
m.add_boolean(False)
password = b(self.password)
m.add_string(password)
```

and change it to:

```python
m.add_boolean(True) # Yes, change password
password = b(self.password)
m.add_string(password)
m.add_string(b("newpassword"))
```

*(I didn't test it though)*

---

Or you can run WinSCP on Linux using Wine. WinSCP can change the password on command-line using the (undocumented) `/newpassword` switch.

```
winscp.com sftp://user:password@example.com /newpassword=newpassword
```